# Wordpress: today date instead of published date in all posts single page

Tags: wordpress

This is a Word Press/PHP question (very beginner, I'm not a programmer). Trying to find were is the code that display the date in posts page because it's showing the today date instead of the post published one. In the post-info.php I found this code displaying date:

```
else {
                if ($info_parts['date']) {
                    $post_date = apply_filters('themerex_filter_post_date', $post_data['post_date'], $post_data['post_id'], $post_data['post_type']);
                    $post_date_diff = themerex_get_date_or_difference($post_date);
                    ?>
                    <span class="post_info_item post_info_posted"><?php echo (in_array($post_data['post_type'], array('post', 'page', 'product')) ? esc_html__('Posted', 'themerex') : ($post_date <= date('Y-m-d') ? esc_html__('Started', 'themerex') : esc_html__('Will start', 'themerex'))); ?> <a href="<?php echo esc_url($post_data['post_link']); ?>" class="post_info_date<?php echo esc_attr($info_parts['snippets'] ? ' date updated' : ''); ?>"<?php echo ($info_parts['snippets'] ? ' itemprop="datePublished" content="'.esc_attr($post_date).'"' : ''); ?>><?php echo esc_html($post_date_diff); ?></a></span>
                    <?php
                }
```

Where to correct this code to show the published post date?
I'm using the bookshelf wordpress theme of themerex, verison 1.6.9
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Modified this line

```
<?php echo esc_html($post_date_diff); ?>
```

like this:

```
<php echo esc_html($post_date); ?>
```